# Is (0-9) a valid regex expression in unix?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, terminal

`[0-9]` means to include a single digit. `(123)` means to include the numbers `123`. `(0123456789)` means to include all those numbers in that order. But `(0-9)` is not a valid expression right? Are ranges allowed inside of ranges?

Comment: `(0-9)` means a capturing group with 3 characters literally: zero, minus, nine.

Comment: *"But (0-9) is not a valid expression right?"* - No it's a perfectly valid regex. `(...)` is a capturing group and not a range. You can always just plug it into an online regex such as https://regex101.com/ to find this out yourself.

Comment: All three answers have been downvoted. Perhaps the downvoter(s?) would care to post an answer.

Comment: Yeah could you add some explanations about what we did wrong? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `[0-9]` will match one single digit character
- `123` is the regex to match the chain `123`
- `0123456789` is the regex to match the chain `0123456789`
- `0-9` will match the string `0-9` literally

Now, if you use parenthesis, you are using **capturing group** that you could refer later in your regex or in your replacement string by **\1** **\2** **\3** etc for respectively the 1st, 2nd and 3rd capturing group.

You could imagine ***a regex that matches a string if 2 identical characters are used in the it***:

```
(.).*\1
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/nFwxRo/1

You have many possible usages of backreferences and capturing groups so I believe they are a fundamental concept to learn if you want to use regex

For more info on regex:

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

To test your regex:

https://regex101.com/

Regex are cool but might be a bit difficult at first glance! Good luck

Answer (score 1):

`(0-9)` would match the string '0-9' literally. The hyphen/minus sign is used inside character sets (things like `[a-z]`) only. Therefore, it is completely valid but does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of regular expressions. `(0-9)` is valid either as a *basic* regular expression or as an *extended* regular expression, with different meanings. In neither case is the `0-9` portion treated as a range.

In a basic regular expression (for example, the kind recognized by the `grep` command), `(0-9)` simply matches that sequence of 5 characters: `'('`, `'0'`, `'-'`, `'9'`, `')'`.

In an extended regular expression (for example, the kind recognize by `egrep` or `grep -E`), `(0-9)` matches the 3-character sequence `'0'`, `'-'`, `'9'`, with the parentheses indicating grouping (and possibly, depending on the context, capturing the contained group for use elsewhere).

https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html